# Get values by key in the Array of object

Tags: javascript

I've an array which contains the objects including various key and values. I'm going to pick out the certain values from the Array and check if the specific value is included or not in the Array.

```
function groupByName (contract) {
 const { age } = contract;

 const groups = [
  {name: 'John', age: 30},
  {name: 'Jack', age: 33},
  {name: 'Tom', age: 40}
  ...
 ];
 ...
}
```

In order to compare the `age` in `groups` array, right now I have to use loop functions and then check one by one.
Like

```
groups.forEach(g => {
 if (g.age === age) {
  ...
 } else {
  ...
 }
});
```

But I don't like this approach and think there are simple and effective way.
Please help me!

Comment: `groups.filter(g => g.age == age)`  try with this

Comment: @lucumt: There's an if/else in the code, so your suggestion won't necessarily help. It really depends on what's inside that if/else (more specifically, what's inside the 'else' part, since your filter basically skips every element which is dealt with inside that part). The question in general isn't very informative when it asks for a "simple and effective way", since the question is - a simple and effective way for doing what?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `filter` to create two sublists

like this

```js
const groups = [
  {name: 'John', age: 30},
  {name: 'Jack', age: 33},
  {name: 'Tom', age: 40}
  ]
  
const withAge = age => groups.filter(g => g.age === age)
const withoutAge = age => groups.filter(g => g.age !== age)

const age30 = withAge(30)

const ageNot30 = withoutAge(30)

age30.forEach(g => {
  console.log('do some stuff with age 30', g)
})

ageNot30.forEach(g => {
  console.log('do some stuff without age 30', g)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can see this function

```
groups.some(p=>r.age===age)//if there is a object meet the criteria, return true, else return false
```

or read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

by the way, if you want to execute the if/else snippet in every loop, maybe you should use forEach